# How to sort similar values in a sorted list (based on second value) of tuples based on another value(third value) in the tuple in descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples of the format

> [("d",21,5),(e,21,4),("a",20,1),("b",20,3),("c",20,2),...]

where the first values (a,b,c etc) are unique and the other two values in tuple might repeat.(like 20)

I want to sort the list based on 2nd element(here 20,21) in tuple in ascending order, like

> [a,b,c,d,e]

Then i want the values sorted based on same numbers like (a,b,c) where sorted based on 20 and (d,e) based on 21 to be sorted based on 3rd value(here 1,2,3,4,5) of tuple in descending order, like

> [b,c,a,d,e]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your original list looks like this:

```
L = [("d",21,5),(e,21,4),("a",20,1),("b",20,3),("c",20,2),...]
```

Then, you can sort it the way you want, by defining a 2-tuple key in the sort function:

```
L.sort(key=lambda t: (t[1],-t[2]))
```

This ensures that the list is sorted by the second element in the tuple, while ties are broken by the negated value of the third element in the tuple (i.e. in descending order by the third element)

Comment: what if i also had another 4th value to break ties in the 3rd value

Comment: @SatishP Then you would add that fourth value to the end of the key.

Comment: If you didn't have to sort one descending, this would be a perfect use of `operator.itemgetter`. Ignoring the descending sort, `L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2))` is super quick.